# How to copy all files without a specific extension to another directory?

Tags: ubuntu, cp

I have two directories `dir1` and `dir2`. I want to copy all the files and folders in `dir1` to `dir2` except the files that have `.txt` extension. How I can do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `rsync` with `--exclude` option.

```
rsync -av --exclude '*.txt' dir1/ dir2/
```

Comment: Let's say that after running the above command, I add a new file with `.jpg` extension to `dir1`. When I run your command again, does the command just adds `.jpg` file to `dir2`? Or the command copy again all the files in `dir1` without `.txt` extention to `dir2`?

Comment: The extension is irrelevant. Rsync has many (many!) flags and options that can customize it's behavior, but usually, by default it just copies the differences. So in your case, it will copy **only** the new jpg file to dir2, or any other files that exist in dir1 and don't exist on dir2 (except for what you exclude, of course), or any changes in the content or attributes in any file from dir1 to dir2. Rsync first compares those dirs, and only then copies the delta.

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
cd dir1 && LC_ALL=C pax -rwpe -'s|.*\.txt||' . ../dir2
```

Beware that at least with the implementation from http://www.mirbsd.org/pax.htm (as found on MirBSD or in the `pax` package on Debian for instance), it also excludes symlinks whose target ends in `.txt` even if the symlinks names themselves don't end in `.txt`.

Another difference with `rsync` is that though it excludes *directories* whose name ends in `.txt`, it doesn't exclude non-txt files in those directories. Add a `-s'|.*\.txt/.*||'` to also exclude those.

`-pe` tries to preserve as much metadata as possible (the list of which varies with the `pax` implementation). With `rsync`, see the `-a` (`-rlptgoD`), `-AXUHN` options to select what you want preserved.